# Метод .map() в Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Я бы хотел понять, почему информация из сервера приходит в течении 2 секунд(что хорошо), но данные из этой информации отображается в течении 4-5 секунд(что плохо).
Вот инфо с api:

```
const Title = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const loaderTwo = useSelector((state) => state.Data.loaderTwo);
  const getProList10Value = useSelector(state=>state.Data.getProList10Value)
  

  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const currentLanguage = i18n.language;


  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProList10())
  }, [dispatch]);

  console.log(getProList10Value);

  const totalPages = Math.ceil(getProList10Value.count / 10);
  const pageNumbers = Array.from(
    { length: totalPages },
    (_, index) => index + 1
  );

  return (
    <div className="title_container">
      <h2 className="head_title_product">{t("newProduct")}</h2>
    
      {loaderTwo ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <Products pageNumbers={pageNumbers} 
          producstListSelectCategory={getProList10Value.results}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Данные передается дальше в компонент Products:

```
<div className="products_box">
          {producstListSelectCategory?.map((data, i) => (
            <ProductListShow key={i} data={data} />
          ))}
        </div>
```

И из этого же компонента в ProductListShow для отображения данных

Comment: попробуй использовать что-то кроме индекса в `key`

Comment: Может у вас в редаксе или по пути от диспатча до рендера что то происходит, что занимает 5 секунд? Я бы отследил всю цепочку вызовов и померил время. Еще, как вариант, вы данные в редаксе меняете, но реакт не понимает, что данные поменялись, затем что то происходит в компонентах и они перерисовываются, уже рисуя новые данные. Такое поведение может быть, если новые данные записываются в один из ключей объекта, в то время, как отслеживается изменение самого объекта. Ссылка на объект не меняется, рекат не видит изменений